# CSS navigation on left side, picture on right issue

Tags: css, css-float

I am not exactly sure how to describe this issue, but heres goes nothing....

I have a navigation on left side of my site..

```
.headerWrapper {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 745px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

and right next to that is a class with an image inside of it....

```
.mainContent {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

the width of the image is 1000px and that is set in the image width attribute.

This layout looks good on my screen, but on other screens the image goes underneath the headerWrapper...Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image goes below because there's not enough width area to fit in both the navigation and image. For minor fixes, try playing with the margin, padding (around 0) of the `.mainContent`, `.headerWrapper` and `body` to fit in both of them side by side.

However, for better adaptability to all resolutions you should use [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mke7E/3/)'s a fiddle. Resize the result window and see the animation.

Basically, using media queries, you can define styling according to window size, for example in your case, you could reduce the size of the image to fit in low-res screens and so on.

Hope it helps. :)